# nginx + apache, редирект с несуществующего поддомена на конкретный поддомен

Tags: nginx, apache

Работает nginx + apache. Один поддомен был ликвидирован и его статьи переехали на те же адреса, но нового поддомена.

В `.conf` старого поддомена я прописал следующие настройки, они работают нормально.

```
server 
{
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/old.site.ru;  
    server_name old.site.ru www.old.site.ru; 
    return 301 https://new.site.ru$request_uri;
}

server 
{
    listen 443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/wildcard.crt; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/wildcard.key;

    server_name old.site.ru www.old.site.ru;

    return 301 https://new.site.ru$request_uri; 
}
```

Сейчас планируется упразднить еще несколько поддоменов с переносом их статей на новые, в связи с чем возникла идея ***удалить ненужные поддомены, чтобы просто ради редиректа не складировать старье*** - пусть где то в общем конфиге будет редирект с конкретных (но уже несуществующих) поддоменов на конкретные новые. А вот это у меня не получилось.

Я полез в `nginx.conf` - что  то никак не заводится.

Что мне необходимо предпринять? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

1. Добавьте в ваш конфиг [маппинг](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) старых и новых доменов:

```
map $host $new_host {
    hostnames;
    old.site.ru new.site.ru;
    site2.ru new2.site.ru
    ...
}
```

2. В блоке server перечисляйте все свои старые домены (поддомены) в директиве [server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).
3. В директиве return используйте переменную $new_host:

```
return 301 https://$new_host$request_uri;
```

4. Обратите внимание на SSL сертификат. Либо на все перечисленные домены должны быть один сертификат, либо имена файлов ключей и сертификатов нужно увязать с переменной $host.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я правильно понимаю, все манипуляции в общем конфигурационном файле?

Comment: конфиг nginx для удобства может разбиваться на отдельные файлы, которые включаются в общий директивой include. Если вам удобнее все иметь в одном файле, то это не воспрещается